# Login to Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cloud-services

I am trying to log in to Azure Active Directory from my web page in cloud services. The log in screen comes up and I am able to log in OK. However when it sends me to my homepage it says "page cannot be displayed". In the Azure Active Directory configuration I added SSL localhost to the APP URI and Reply URL and configured the properties in VS2013 to show SSL = True and set the project URL to the localhost. I was able to access the page before I added the log in screen.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Relevant web.config settings:

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
 <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
 <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="login.windows.net/conpro.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/…; />
 <add key="ida:Realm" value="localhost:44307/"; />
 <add key="ida:AudienceUri" value="localhost:44307/"; />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to use Azure AD to authenticate users of an ASP.NET app running as a cloud service in Azure?

Comment: Yes that is my goal. I am just trying to log in and access my home page.

Comment: Are you trying to access the app in Azure or on your local machine?  If it's in Azure then your configuration should have your xxxx.cloudapp.net URL instead of localhost.

Comment: Thank you for the up vote.  I have tried both the local host and https://conpro.cloudapp.net both have failed.  I am away from my computer,  I will post the screen shots within the hour.

Comment: I edited my original question to include the screenshots.

Comment: How did you configure authentication in your app?

Comment: <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://login.windows.net/conpro.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:Realm" value="https://localhost:44307/" />
    <add key="ida:AudienceUri" value="https://localhost:44307/" />
  </appSettings>

Comment: it is from the webconfig file

Answer (score 1):

Your web.config URI values need to include `https://`.  I'd suggest taking a look at [this sample app](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WSFederation-DotNet) as well.